# CSS: how do I make the background of Atom text editor seethrough?

Tags: css, atom-editor

I have a `compositor`, `picom`, and with everything else, it seems to work. I have tried to do the following:

```
atom-text-editor {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

But that makes it a little darker, not even black. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: I also have a theme, do I have to change something with that?

Answer (score 0):

Technically this (`background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`) is not even a color. This is equal to `transparent`.

You can use something like this:

```
atom-text-editor {
  background-color: #1f2229;
}
```

Comment: well yes, but I want to have it transparent, that simply changes the color. If I do something like
`background-color: #771f2229`
it is not transparent at all.

Comment: @OttoCrawford Can you plz elaborate and you can use singe (`) to add highlighted text in comments

Comment: so, I am trying to make the background of the text editor (a little bit) transparent. The hex-color you have provided is not with alpha. I also tried to use an 8-character hex, but it does not yield transparency.